# Optimizing neo4j query with multiple merges

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

**What I need to do**

For each query I need to find the user by device_id, or create a new node if doesn't exist. And for each, I need to update/create a few edges if `row`s contains certain properties. The load is massive(about 20k per second) and neo4j slows down. Each batch size is exactly 20k. Here is my query:

```
UNWIND {batch} as row 
MERGE (m:User {device_id: row.device_id})
FOREACH (ignore IN CASE WHEN row.type IS NOT NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
    MERGE (e:Event {type: row.type}) 
    MERGE (m) -[r:REL]-> (e) 
    SET r.count = ( CASE r.count WHEN NULL THEN 1 ELSE r.count + 1 END) 
)
FOREACH (ignore IN CASE WHEN row.country IS NOT NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END | 
    MERGE (c:Country {id: row.country}) 
    MERGE (m) -[:Belongs]-> (c) 
)
WITH m, ( CASE row.user_id WHEN NULL THEN m.user_id ELSE row.user_id END) AS user_id 
SET m.user_id = user_id
```

Comment: What about indexes?

Comment: @stdob i have unique constraints on device_id Event.type and country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by decreasing the batch size to 5k and running a few of those inside a transaction in parallel  before committing.